# Fixed by myself: Change color of button when pressed

Tags: swiftui, uibutton

I have a ChoiceTextView.swift-file that contains the look of the button

```SwiftUI
var body: some View {
        Text(choiceText)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: screenSize.width - 100, height: 100)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(.blue)
                )
    }
```

and in my ContentView.swift in my QuizApp shows a button for every answer in my array

```SwiftUI
ForEach(0..<question.possibleAnswers.count) { answerIndex in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.checkAnswer(answerIndex)
                    }, label: {
                        ChoiceTextView(choiceText: question.possibleAnswers[answerIndex])
                            .frame(width: screenSize.width - 100, height: 100)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(answerIndex == selectedAnswerIndex  && answerIndex == question.correctAnswer ? Color.green : Color.red)
                            )
                            .padding(5)
                    })
                }
```

This works fine and the app works so far and the button reacts and changes the color to green, if I press the correct answer and red, when I press the wrong answer. Sadly the color change is quite difficult to see because it just appears for a split of a second.

If I disable `.fill(.blue)` in my ChoiceTextView.swift, the color change is much better visible but the button still appears in blue. When I press the button the color changes for some milliseconds and the color looks darken as if both colors would be shown at the same time. So I'd like to change the button Color to either green or red and the button should show the color for a short duration of 1s.

The duration is not implemented by me yet since I already have trouble with the color being shown as I like to.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to achieve. Also, your code has missing implementations. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Use button style to customise press behaviour https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyle

Comment: @soundflix thx for helping me improving how to prepare better questions!! That really helped me in many ways. First I learned more about this platform and second in rewriting the code to make a small reproducable programm I somehow fixed my issue and now it is working. :)

Comment: It's also my experience, preparing a reproducible example I often solve the problem myself - and learn why. Cheers!

Comment: Btw, you are welcome to post your own solution as an answer.

Comment: @soundflix I had too many of `.fill(.blue)` in my code and they were overlapping and all tried to be somehow being on the top layer. Should I delete my not so usefull question or can I close it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself while writing a reproducable code. I had too many `.fill(.blue)` in my code and while cleaning it up, it startet to work.